# How to catch jquery exceptions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

Sometimes when i debuggind js code debugger jump to jquery source file and of course i cannt understand anything in this obfuscated code. How to find any humanreadeble message about exception?

Comment: Use the non-compressed version of jQuery during development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use non-minified JQuery code during development. The cause of the error is often not laid at jQuery, but at your implementation.

When you've added a new feature, which throws an error, read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/) to find how to apply the function in the right way.